Wake topology, additive groups and Neighborhood system.
If a family $ C' $ of real-valued functions on $ X $ is an additive group, contains the constant functions, and contains the absolute value of each of its members, then the collection of sets of the form
$
\{ y \in X : |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon \} \quad (f \in C', \epsilon > 0)
$
is a base of neighborhoods of $ x $ for each $ x \in X $, in the weak topology induced by $ C' $.
I'm working with the ring of Continuous functions from any topological space to $ \mathbb{R} $ with usual operations. If I want to prove that the set is a neighborhood system, how does knowing what they tell me help? Why can't I proceed by taking a function and seeing that it is in the interior of one of those things? I have worked very little with topological spaces and even less with function spaces, so it's very abstract for me to know what I have to do.
Can u help me please? This exercise is from the book "Rings of Continuous Functions" by Leonard Gillman (Chapter 3, 3G)

This answer doesn’t provide a proof, but an intuitive explanation that you will hopefully find helpful.
« Why can't I proceed by taking a function and seeing that it is in the interior of one of those sets? » The sets in question form a base of neighbourhoods of $x \in X$ where $X$ has the weak topology induced by $\textit{C’}$. The last information is very important. Be careful, $X$ is a space, it isn’t necessarily a function space. The functions in $\textit{C’}$ go from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and they definitely aren’t what you want - or could possibly have - in that base. However, those functions allow you to construct a base of neighbourhoods of $x \in X$ by transporting the notion of “closeness” from $\mathbb{R}$ to $X$ through continuous functions. The functions in $\textit{C’}$ are continuous, only because you are asked to consider a weak topology on $X$ induced by $\textit{C’}$.
Here are few important things to keep in mind when thinking about this problem :

A base of neighbourhoods of $x \in X $ is a set of open subsets of $X$ denoted $\textit{N(x)}$ such that whenever you take any neighbour $V$ of $x$ in $X$, there is a neighbourhood $U \in  \textit{N(x)}$ such that $U \subset V$. In other words, « you always can go deeper/closer to $x$ with the neighbourhoods in the base» - by the way, that phrase is something that echoes the notion of continuity. Check the notion of filters for more information and intuition. However, I didn’t mean to simply restate here the
definition of a neighbourhood system. I want to make a remark that
any topological notion is extremely dependent on the topology you
are considering on $X$. Something true for one topology on $X$
isn’t necessarily true for another topology on $X$. Here, you
consider a weak topology induced by $\textit{C’}$. Meaning the
coarsest (smallest) topology such the all of the functions from
$\textit{C’}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ are continuous. You don’t have any
other supplementary open sets, but only and exactly the ones
necessary for those functions to be continuous, and that’s it.
Loosely speaking, a topology on $X$ allows us to have a notion of « closeness » of elements in $X$ that is more general than the one given by metric. It’s especially useful, since not all spaces are metrisable (have a metric). And closeness on the other hand allows us to talk about continuity of functions. Functions that don’t go from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ like usually in real analysis, but ones that go from $X \to  \mathbb{R}$.
Finally, the real numbers are what is pleasant and understandable, at least in this context. In $\mathbb{R}$ with the canonical topology considering a base of neighbourhoods is something very easy. But it isn’t the case for any space with some random topology. Here we pick such a topology so that we can nicely transport what is easy in $\mathbb{R}$ to $X$.

The exercice goal is to show that it is enough to run through all functions in $\textit{C’}$, all epsilons greater than zero, at each time create a set of all the $y$ that fulfill the given condition and add it to the collection, by the time you are done, you have a base of neighbourhoods of $x \in X$ where $X$ has the weak topology induced by $\textit{C’}$. I leave you to wonder why it isn’t the case if $\textit{C’}$ isn’t stable by addition and/or it doesn’t contain the constant functions and/or doesn’t contain the absolute value of each of its members.
